# Keyboard shortcut for moving a code editor tab to a new window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, code-editor

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2017 for undocking a tab and putting it in a seperate window? Right now I can only do it by dragging the tab header down with my mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to the **Window.Float** command.